# Why geom_boxplot identify more outliers than base boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Here is a reproducible example, the last treatment group has one more outliers identified compared to the base boxplot.

[image: bug1]
[image: bug2]

```

```
dta <- structure(list(Treatment = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D"), `Cage No.` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 
108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 201, 202, 203, 204, 
205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 301, 
302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 
315, 316, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 
210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 
307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316), variable = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Eggs Laid", 
"Eggs Cracked", "Eggs Set", "Viable Embryos", "Live 3wk Embryos", 
"Number of Hatchlings", "14 d old survivors", "Egg shell thickness", 
"Egg shell strength", "Hatchling wt", "14 d old survivor wt", 
"Food consumption (mean g/bird/day)", "Initial male wt", "Terminal male wt", 
"Initial female wt", "Terminal female wt"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1.32126666666667, 1.36686666666667, 
    1.368, 1.34973333333333, 1.332, 1.3774, 1.36773333333333, 
    1.36006666666667, 1.35286666666667, 1.37786666666667, 1.373, 
    1.352, 1.35186666666667, 1.391, 1.37173333333333, 1.34175, 
    1.33586666666667, 1.35106666666667, 1.3622, 1.3526, 1.35506666666667, 
    1.34593333333333, 1.3446, 1.37533333333333, 1.32873333333333, 
    1.38413333333333, 1.38173333333333, 1.3572, 1.35773333333333, 
    1.3472, 1.37358333333333, 1.3568, 1.34993333333333, 1.3688, 
    1.38126666666667, 1.3638, 1.3764, 1.35786666666667, 1.3358, 
    1.35973333333333, 1.37066666666667, 1.34126666666667, 1.39126666666667, 
    1.41633333333333, 1.39593333333333, 1.3682, 1.332, 1.36606666666667, 
    1.3442, 1.3262, 1.35253333333333, 1.35066666666667, 1.37973333333333, 
    1.38166666666667, 1.35326666666667, 1.3518, 1.34486666666667, 
    1.36173333333333, 1.4026, 1.33053333333333, 1.3356, 1.34375, 
    1.34146666666667, 1.37606666666667)), .Names = c("Treatment", 
"Cage No.", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 
126L, 127L, 128L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 
457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 
468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 
479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 
490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 
501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 
512L))

ggplot(data=subset(dta,variable=="Egg shell thickness"),aes(x=Treatment,y=value,fill=Treatment))+stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')+geom_boxplot()
windows()
boxplot(value~Treatment,data=subset(dta,variable=="Egg shell thickness"))

ggplot(data=subset(dta,variable=="Eggs Cracked"),aes(x=Treatment,y=value,fill=Treatment))+stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')+geom_boxplot()
windows()
boxplot(value~Treatment,data=subset(dta,variable=="Eggs Cracked"))
```

```

Comment: If one of them is wrong (and I'm guessing it would be ggplot2) then should you be addressing this to the package author? I've looked at the documentation and it sounds as though @hadley thinks he might have been doing something different than the graphics::boxplot but I could not figure out from the help pages how outliers are defined differently.

Comment: I think it must be that I did something wrong or my computer, but I have spent hours on figuring out where and why and getting nowhere. I will post to github if this is the right behaviour of geom_boxplot.

Comment: Why aren't you figuring out what the right answer should be?

Comment: I guess sometimes I just got carried away by my wrong belief and could not get back in the right direction of finding the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculation method for the hinges is different. `geom_boxplot()` uses actual 1st & third quantiles, `boxplot()` uses a version of this which is not the same for even n.

This is well documented in both `?geom_boxplot` and `?boxplot.stats`

Comment: Do you know the reason why boxplot.stats use a version different from the actual quartiles for even n?

Comment: There are at least 9 different definitions of the 25th and 75th quantiles. So the phrase "actual quartiles" is not well defined. The choice made by base R is to use a particular value in the data.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, I see.